# Does -eq works for multiple extensions in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Heys guys,

So I wrote a small script in powershell (very new to this). Haven’t touched anything in like 10 years but here it goes:

The script is supposed to pull cert dates from a specific folder on c:\ for all my computers on the network (includes some computers for my siblings in different states) and save the result as a text file on my desktop.

I’m just curious about the extension in general. If there’s multiple certs within the folder with different extensions can I use -eq to pull data for both extensions using the same line. Say the folder path is C:\List\certificates (will not be pulling any data from cert store so no pfx files) and I used this line in my code:

```
$certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path $using:certPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq “.cer .key”}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [containment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#containment-operators) for this, either `-in` or `-contains`:

```bash
$certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path $using:certPath -Recurse |
    Where-Object Extension -In '.cer', '.key'
```

Using `Get-ChildItem` built-in filtering parameter `-Include` should work too:

```bash
$certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path $using:certPath -Recurse -Include *.cer, *.key
```

Or you can use `-Match` and a regex pattern:

```bash
$certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path $using:certPath -Recurse |
    Where-Object Extension -Match '\.(?:cer|key)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has a built in provider for working with certs.

Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\my | Format-Table NotBefore,NotAfter,Thumbprint

Comment: It's great that you're a regular contributor here, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - it seems like in the past others have done that for you.